# Evaluating Temperature using Antoine Eq with Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I need help with getting the temp using Antoine Eq by making use of classes.

My root action is failing and I don't know why.

My code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root

class Chemical(object):

    def __init__(self, name_1, balance_1, name_2, balance_2):
        self.name = name_1 + ' ' + '+' + ' ' + name_2
        self.data_1 = []
        self.data_2 = []
        self.data_1 = balance_1
        self.data_2 = balance_2

    def __str__(self):
        if (self.name):
            return "Mixture: %s" % (self.name)
        else:
            return None

    def bubble_solve(self,a,P = 1.01,T = 300):
        A1,B1,C1 = self.data_1
        A2,B2,C2 = self.data_2
        PA = 10**(A1 - B1/(C1+T)) 
        PB = 10**(A2 - B2/(C2+T)) 
        sol = root(lambda T: P - (a*PA + (1-a)*PB),T)
        return sol.x[0]

    def dew_solve(self, b, P = 1.01, T = 300):
        A1,B1,C1 = self.data_1
        A2,B2,C2 = self.data_2
        PA = 10**(A1 - B1/(C1+T)) 
        PB = 10**(A2 - B2/(C2+T)) 
        sol = root(lambda T: 1 - (b*P/PA + (1-b)*P/PB), T)
        return sol.x[0]


mixture = Chemical('benzene', [ 3.98523 , 1184.24 , -55.578], 'toulene', 
[4.05043 , 1327.62 , -55.528])
print(mixture)
print()

print(mixture.bubble_solve(0.5)) #at a = 0.5
print(mixture.bubble_solve(0.5,2)) #at a = 0.5 and P = 2
print(mixture.dew_solve(0.5)) #at b = 0.5
print(mixture.dew_solve(0.5,2)) #at b = 0.5 and P = 2
```

This is what my code is printing:

```
Mixture: benzene + toulene

300.0
300.0
300.0
300.0
```

However, the answers need to be:
365.087, 390.14188, 371.7743, 396.688.

Why does the root action fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow, @Nathaniel!

The issue is in your `PA`, `PB`, and `sol` lines in `bubble_solve` and `dew_solve`. You seem to be mixing constants with independent variables! For instance, with your bubble solve, you have the default value of 300 set for `T`. Thus in the `PA` line, the value 300 is being used for `T`! One way to fix this would be the following:

```
    ...
    def bubble_solve(self,a,P = 1.01,T = 300):
        A1,B1,C1 = self.data_1
        A2,B2,C2 = self.data_2
        PA = lambda x: 10**(A1 - B1/(C1+x)) 
        PB = lambda x: 10**(A2 - B2/(C2+x)) 
        sol = root(lambda x: P - (a*PA(x) + (1-a)*PB(x)),T)
        return sol.x[0]

    def dew_solve(self, b, P = 1.01, T = 300):
        A1,B1,C1 = self.data_1
        A2,B2,C2 = self.data_2
        PA = lambda x: 10**(A1 - B1/(C1+x)) 
        PB = lambda x: 10**(A2 - B2/(C2+x)) 
        sol = root(lambda x: 1 - (b*P/PA(x) + (1-b)*P/PB(x)), T)
        return sol.x[0]
    ...
```

This will return the values you have expected. Note that I use `x` as the independent variable for `PA` and `PB`, but that it's arbitrary. However, it's probably best to not reuse `T` for your anonymous functions if you are passing values to it.

Comment: This worked like a charm!! Thanks so much for your help! Worked on this for hours and turns out it was just a single character that was the bug.